# \placeongrid and \moveongrid not working in ConTeXt

Tags: context, grid-typesetting

I am trying to use the grid features in ConTeXt, but some of the commands are somehow not recognized by the compiler.

Whenever I try to use the commands
`\placeongrid` or `\moveongrid`, the compiler exits with an error message such as:

```
l.27 \moveongrid [both] ? >Exit code: -1073741510
```

the grid=yes option for the `\setuplayout` works well, but this is not what I intend to use.

I have both the TeXLive 2012 package and the ConTeXt Standalone (ver. 2012.10.17), and both distributions produce the same error message.

One concern is that when I try to update my ConTeXt standalone files, I get a message saying

```
The program can't start because kpathsea611.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.
```

I wonder if this has any relevance to the issue. Btw, I am on a Win7-x64 system.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: 1. have you read the grid related instructions in [the reference](http://context.aanhet.net/svn/contextman/context-reference/en/co-pagedesign.pdf)? 2. ``\moveongrid`` is mkii only, if you think you need it you will have to run your file through *texexec*. 3. kpathsea is linked into LuaTeX. It is, however, unnecessary and even disabled in Context (mkiv) so afaict the warning shouldn’t hurt.

Comment: 1. yes I am relying on this reference
2. this explains why I am having problems since I have been using *context* instead of *texexec*. Using *texexec* solved the problem. thank you!
3. actually, the kpathsea problem is quite annoying since it makes the *texexec* unavailable for the standalone package. The distribution that comes with the TeX Live package has no problems with kpathsea so this can be my solution.
4. I found an adhoc solution in case I want to use *context*. Repeated usage of `\startlinecorrection` and `\stoplinecorrection` until I get desired results seems to work a bit.

Comment: For some reason it is not mentioned in the manual that you do in fact need ``\setuplayout[grid=yes]`` (or ``strict`` or ``verystrict``) to activate snapping in the first place. What do you mean when you say you *do not intend to use it*? Btw. here is some additional documentation in [the details doc](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/details.pdf) and on [the wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Working_on_Grid) in case you missed it.

Comment: In fact, I have just been testing and noticed that without the `[grid =yes]` the commands don't make a difference. Guess I kinda misunderstood the mechanism. I thought that the snapping commands would effectively bring in a grid locally. Now, my options seem to be narrowed down to either using the global grid setting or just living with `\startlinecorrection` on a non-grid. Probably the grid is the way to go. Anyway, thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

The command `\moveongrid` is specific to MkII and has been
[removed in MkIV](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/HEAD:/tex/context/base/spac-ver.mkiv#l1443).
It used to be a fairly low-level command that others like `\placeongrid`
built onto.
Since most of the grid functionality has been reimplemented in Lua as part of a
[gigantic callback](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/refs/heads/origin:/tex/context/base/spac-ver.lua#l820),
`\moveongrid` lacks an equivalent on the TeX end.
However, there is the comparably low-level counterpart `\snaptogrid` that
user macros like for instance the `\startlinecorrection` environment rely on.

`\snaptogrid` receives an `\hbox` or `\vbox` as mandatory argument (custom
boxes created by `\newbox` won’t cut it).
An optional first argument determines the snapping method.
If it is missing, it defaults to the globally active one.
A short example demonstrating three of the available methods:

```
\useMPlibrary [dum]
\setuppapersize [A6]
\showgrid
\setuplayout [grid=yes] %% set the global snap method

\def \makedummy {
  %% create a dummy figure with a vsize that is not a multiple of the
  %% leading
  \externalfigure [dummy] [height=\dimexpr4.25\lineheight]%
}

\starttext
  \input ward \par

  method: default
  \snaptogrid\vbox{\makedummy} \par
  \input ward \par

  method: top
  \snaptogrid [top] \vbox{\makedummy} \par
  \input ward \par

  method: line
  \snaptogrid [line] \vbox{\makedummy} \par
  \input ward \par
\stoptext
```

[image: Typeset result]

The default method is `yes` (aliases: `normal` and `standard`).
For an exhaustive list of available methods see the
[wiki](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/snaptogrid).